# Segmentation fault when using taps to export database from heroku

Tags: mysql, postgresql, heroku, segmentation-fault, taps

I'm using taps to export PostgreSql database from Heroku to my locally Mysql2 database, when I run the following commands in terminal,

```
heroku db:pull mysql2://root:@127.0.0.1/spendon_dev --app huanarle
```

it says

```
/Users/huangjin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]
```

what's the problem? please help me

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem and trying to work it out as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to a similar question: [Heroku db:push fails with segfault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389832/heroku-dbpush-fails-with-segfault)

You need to reinstall the heroku gem, and the taps gem

```
gem install heroku
sudo gem install taps
```

Best of luck to you!