# heroku db:pull using wrong ruby version (1.8.7 instead of 1.9.3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-1.9.3, taps

I am using ruby 1.9.3

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ] ruby-1.9.2-p320 [ x86_64 ] => ruby-1.9.3-p125 [ x86_64 ] ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ] ruby-1.9.3-p286 [ x86_64 ] * ruby-1.9.3-p327 [ x86_64 ]
```

I installed gem taps to pull a Heroku database.

But I am having the following problem:

```
$ heroku db:pull --account personal --app myherokuapp
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
```

Abort trap: 6
Why is this happening?

Comment: Apparently uninstalling and reinstalling the heroku gem and taps gems may help. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389832/heroku-dbpush-fails-with-segfault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uninstalling and reinstalling the heroku gem and taps gems worked